# How to make insert query using SQLiteCommand?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a piece of code, that does not work for me always. Sometimes it returns error about database locked, sometimes about connection.

This is code:

```
string sql = String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values);
SQLiteConnection myConn = null;
try 
{
    myConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
    myConn.Open();

    using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql))
    {
        sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rows = sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return !(rows == 0);
    }
} 
finally 
{
    myConn.Close();
}
```

What I do wrong?

Error is:

> No connection associated with this command
>
> ```
>    в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.InitializeForReader()
>    в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> ```
>
> behavior)
>          в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

In line:

```
int rows = sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: personally I would change the `finally` section of your code to be a `catch` and you do not need to call the `myConn.Close()` you are currently inside of a `using(){}` so it will auto dispose of that object when you leave the using code block.. also checkout this posting about Sqlite locks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800174/how-do-i-stop-the-the-database-file-is-locked-exception

Comment: Okay, wil try, but dont think that is reason. I will post error now

Comment: your error seems to have nothing to do with the current code.. you are not calling `ExecuteReader` in that Insert statement.. also try doing a sqlcommand.Commit() do a search thru all your code to find where you are calling `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: I use INSERT query, seemd I dont need use `ExecuteReade`

Comment: Would be great to see full sample how to do that according my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to [assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.-ctor?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteCommand__ctor_System_String_Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteConnection_) the `Connection` to the `Command`:

> No connection associated with this command

```
using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql))
```

should thus be:

```
using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn))
```

Comment: It still gives me an error: "Database is locked" when I execute this operation

Comment: See a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232613/database-is-locked-sqcommand-executenonquery