# Database is locked sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
string sql = String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values);
SQLiteConnection myConn = null;
try 
{
    myConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
    myConn.Open();

    using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn))
    {
        sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rows = sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return !(rows == 0);
    }
} 
finally 
{
    myConn.Close();
}
```

It returns always an error: `Database is locked` in line:

```
int rows = sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Whu does it happen?

Comment: Please post the value in your `sql` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the database connection is left open somewhere when `sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` method executed (which the lock still apply for previous connection), hence you need to refactor by wrapping *every* `SQLiteConnection` instance with `using` statement block like this:

```
string sql = String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values);
using (SQLiteConnection myConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
{
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn))
        {
            sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
            int rows = sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return !(rows == 0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // do exception handling
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Writing to a database file](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

Comment: I will try, and response here

Comment: Can you share example how to use this for select query?

Comment: The select query is similar, but... use `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. Regarding database locked, are you sure you're already wrap *all* `SQLiteConnection` in `using` statement block?

Comment: Yes,  so what does return ExecuteReader?